# htacces Переадресация на другой url. Определение https протокола

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Если файлы `file1` или `file2` запрашиваются с https-страницы, то фронтенд должен отдавать эти файлы из `/seo/https/`.
Пробую сделать так, почему это не работает?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO} https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(file1.html)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(file2.html)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /seo/https/%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: RewriteEngine On

Comment: это тоже прописаано

Comment: Вы уверены, что в `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` есть `https`? И есть ли вообще `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` в наличии?

Comment: да, в php скрипте проверил через var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) - возвращает https

Comment: А файлы запрашиваются в таком виде `https://mysite.com/file1.html` или в таком `https://mysite.com/много/непонятных/буков/file1.html`?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было прописывать так:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
```

а не так:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO} https
```